# A Conjecture about the $K$-automorphisms of a field $L$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

All the subfields discussed in the following questions are subfields of $\mathbb{C}$.

Given a finite normal extension $L:K$, there exists a tower of subfields $L = K_n \subseteq  ... \subseteq K_0 = K$ such that $K_i = K_{i-1}(x_i)$ for some $x_i \in L$.

Thus $$[K_n:K_0] = [K_n:K_{n-1}]...[K_1:K_0]$$

and if we let $p_i$ be the minimal polynomial of $x_i$ over $K_{i-1}$, and $\partial p_i$ be the degree of such polynomial, we can write

$$[K_n:K_0] = \partial p_n ... \partial p_1$$

Noticing that the $\partial p_i$ zeroes of each $p_i$ are different and that for each zeroes $\alpha, \beta$ of any $p_i$ there is a $K$-automorphism $\tau$ of $L$ such that $\tau (\alpha) = \beta$, it seems natural to wonder if the following conjecture is true:

Given the sets {$\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$} and {$\beta_1, ... ,\beta_n$} such that $a_i$ and $b_i$ are zeroes of $p_i$ , there exists a $K$-automorphism $\tau$ of $L$ such that, $\tau(\alpha_i)=\beta_i$ for all $i$.

---

Many theorems of the book I'm reading seem to hint at the statement above being true, yet it has not been proven in any of the chapters I've read. Such statement would, for instance, imply the existence of $[K_n:K_0]$ different $K$-automorphisms of $L$.

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts.

Comment: If that was true then the Galois group of any extension of degree $d$ of ${\mathbb Q}$ would be $S_d$, which is not the case. Note that you can take $n=1$ in your chain of subfields, because finite extensions in characteristic $0$ are simple.

Comment: Do you want to put extra conditions on $[K_{i}:K_{i-1}]$? Because otherwise, as Derek Holt notes, you can find $x\in L$ such that $L=K(x)$. Also, you want to be careful: sure, if you have $K<K(x_1)<K(x_1,x_2)$, and $y_1\in K$ is conjugate to $x_1$, then you can find an automorphism of $K(x_1)$ over $K$ that maps $x_1$ to $y_1$; and that will extend to an automorphism of $K(x_1,x_2)$ over $K$ under suitable hypotheses. But you now may not be free to choose what happens to $x_2$. (Cont)

Comment: For example, say $x_1=\sqrt{2}$, $y_1=-\sqrt{2}$, and $x_2 = \sqrt[4]{2}$. Your map that sends $x_1$ to $y_1$ extends to map on the (normal closure) of $K(x_1,x_2)$, but now $x_2$ must map to an element whose square is $y_1$, and not just to an arbitrary root of $x^4-2$; in particular, it cannot map to itself or to $-\sqrt[4]{2}$. So you are not as free as you seem to think you are.